# Bad assignment of IPs with custom bridge in docker 1.6

Tags: docker

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with custom bridge for docker. In docker 1.5 assignment of IP addresses work correctly. This means gateway has IP 192.168.100.1, docker bridge has IP 192.168.100.2. When I create a container in docker 1.5 the new created container get IP 192.168.100.3 and up IPs which is correct behavior. When I upgrade docker 1.5 to 1.6 this somehow get broken and docker assign to new created container IP 192.168.100.1 and another container get increments 100.2, 100.3 and so. I don't change anything except of updating docker to last stable version. I have tested this also with other distribution debian 8 or ubuntu 15.04 with the same result as on 14.04.

I use DOCKER_OPTS argument set to --bridge=docker0. This setting works with docker 1.5 and the IP are correctly assign to created containers.

Has someone the same problem? Is there any fix for it or some workaround?

Thank you!